# Revmob Unity3D SDK for Amazon

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, amazon-appstore, revmob

I've just published my Android game to the play store [here](http://goo.gl/6UJtSI). Now I want to publish the same app to Amazon. I've used Revmob ad network in that. Now I want to publish it on Amazon too. I can see that Amazon is supported in Revmob Android SDK, we just need to change the App-ID. Revmob documentation however, doesn't give any clue on how to do the same thing in their Unity SDK?

I am currently using it this way -

```
private static readonly Dictionary<String, String> REVMOB_APP_IDS = new Dictionary<String, String>() {
#if UNITY_AMAZON
        {"Android","AMAZON_ID"},
#else
        { "Android", "ANDROID_ID"},
#endif
        { "IOS", "IOS_ID" }
};
```

Is it the correct way? Or should I use "Amazon" as key for amazon ID instead?

Have anyone else used Revmob for their Amazon games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "Android" as the key with Amazon_ID as the value.

If I'm not mistaking, #if UNITY_AMAZON does not exist. The way I'm doing it is quite simple. I'm building two different apks. One for google and one for amazon. In my script I have a bool isAmazon. When I'm building for google I set it to false, and if I'm building for Amazon I set it to true.

```c#
    public bool IsAmazon;
#if (UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_ANDROID) && !UNITY_EDITOR
    private static Dictionary<string,string> REVMOB_APP_IDS = new Dictionary<string, string> ();

    private RevMobBanner _banner;

    private RevMob revmob;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if (IsAmazon)
            REVMOB_APP_IDS.Add ("Android", "YOUR_AMAZON_ID");
        else
            REVMOB_APP_IDS.Add ("Android", "YOUR_ANDROID_ID");

        REVMOB_APP_IDS.Add ("IOS", "YOUR_IOS_ID");
        revmob = RevMob.Start (REVMOB_APP_IDS, gameObject.name);
        revmob.SetTestingMode (RevMob.Test.WITH_ADS);
    }
#endif
```

Comment: I've used a #define UNITY_AMAZON. When I build for Google Play, I just comment that line. Thanks for the answer. It means I am doing the right thing.